# Prototype focusFirstElement() causes form to 'disappear' in IE

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, prototypejs

Strange bug I'm getting. I have a login form that is hidden by default, once a user clicks on an observed element, the element containing the form slides down (using Effect.BlidnDown in Scriptaculous)

Here is the function, which is part of the 'Interface' object:

```
revealLoginForm: function() {
    $('a_login').blur();
    if (!$('hform').visible()) {
        Effect.BlindDown('hform', {
            duration: 0.4,
            afterFinish: function() {
                $('f_login').focusFirstElement();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('f_login').focusFirstElement();
    }
},
```

The event observation:

```
 Event.observe('a_login', 'click', Interface.revealLoginForm);
```

And the HTML:

```
<a id='a_login' href='javascript:void(0);'>Login to My Account</a>
....
<div id='hform' style='display:none;'>
<form id='f_login' action='...' method='post' name='sidelogin'>
<table cellspacing='0' class='login'>
<tr>
<th>Login ID:</th><td><input style='padding:2px;' type='text' size='18' name='enc_loginname' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Password:</th><td><input style='padding:2px;' type='password' size='18' name='enc_password' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th></th><td><input type='submit' class='submit' value='Login &raquo;' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

If I disable the  $('f_login').focusFirstElement(); command in revealLoginForm(), the form does not disappear. What's strange is, the other call to this function does not adversely affect the element, it only seems to happen when called within the afterFinish callback to the Effect.BlindDown function.

Any ideas? It would be nice to have the first element of this form selected once the form has appeared. This works fine in Firefox.. it's just IE (Im using IE7) that's causing problems (go figure...)

Comment: I've noticed (using the IE Developer app) that the table nested inside the form appears at the x0,y0 coordinates of the document. Strangeness, since there is no positioning that I'm aware of being done.

Comment: This, of course is a small issue - since all my Javascript files get parsed with PHP, I just allow the offending line to be printed in all browsers except IE. IE users will have to click on the first element themselves....

Comment: Have you tried using the autofocus HTML5 form element attribute? That would get you this behavior for free in modern browsers.